# Efficient Penalized MLE to Maintain Stationarity

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, matlab, regularization

I am trying to penalize a likelihood function, $-\log f(Y|\theta)$, to maintain stationarity of the autoregressive process.

An vector autoregressive process is said to be stationary if the spectral radius (maximum absolute value of eigenvalues) is less than unity, $\varphi(\Phi)<1$ for the process:

$x_t = \mu + \Phi x_{t-1} + \Sigma \varepsilon_t$

So I'd like to penalize any parameterization where $\varphi(\Phi)\ge 1$, while maintaining continuity of the objective function, $-\log f(Y|\theta) + p(\varphi(\Phi))$.

I've chosen $p(\varphi(\Phi)) = 3(\arctan(7500*(\varphi(\Phi)-.998))-atan(-100000)))$, which is continuous but still gives a very sharp increase in the penalized objective as the spectral radius gets very close to 1, and not much of a penalization if say $\varphi(\Phi)=0.995$.

The issue has been using MATLAB's fmincon, there are times I see the objective rise for maybe 20 or 40 iterations before decreasing. I think this is being caused by a large spike in the gradient.

Might anyone have a better suggestion for penalization function based on my goal?

Comment: A classic in the topic of constrained optimization is the [log barrier function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_function).